# How to expand an unordered list down to a certain link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically built unordered list like below, and I want to find a way to expand all the nodes above the link with a certain id once the list is loaded using jquery,

For example I might want to expand all the nodes required for the link with the id=1905 to be visiblem and leave all other nodes collapsed.

Hope this makes sense.

```
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="inactive" href="#"><img src="images/folder.png">Baking</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="inactive" href="#">Bars</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="1905" class="rlink" href="url">Rasberry Crumb Breakfast Bars</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a id="1803" class="rlink" href="url">text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

So the list would initially load like this

[image]

And I would want to expand it like this

[image]

Comment: Do the expanded items have `class="active"` as opposed to the `class="inactive"` from your code?

Comment: Check following this can be helpful to you....
http://www.fluidbyte.net/simple-jquery-expandcollapse-unordered-lists

Comment: Please post a demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar. Then we have something to work with: help *us* to help *you*.

Answer (score 0):

You could try going up the parent nodes of the element you want and activate them:

```
var parentList= $('#link1905').closest('ul');

while (parentList.length > 0) {
    parentList.prev('a').removeClass('inactive'); /* and/or .addClass('active'); */

    parentList = parentList.closest('ul');
}
```

Also you must start your element id's with a letter: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input, but I solved it myself. Also thanks for the heads up on numeric ids.